# Не могу получить данные всех пользователей Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-database

```
func fetchUser() {


    FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        print(snapshot)

        }, withCancel: nil)

}
```

Запрос не работает. Может ошибка в rules database ?

Answer (score 0):

Информации в вашем вопросе не достаточно для точного ответа, но может поможет это:
В FIRDatabase нет по дефолту сущности users. При регистрации пользователя в FIRAuth следует добавлять собственноручно созданный элемент в FIRDatabase в узел users. 
Что-то вроде этого вписать в регистрацию помимо FIRAuth.auth()!.createUser:

```
let newUser = UserItem(uid: < Value >, email: < Value >, login: < Value >, createdDate: < Value >)

// Create a child path with a key set to the uid underneath the "users" node
let refToMainDB = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "< PathToMainDB >")
refToMainDB.child("users").child(< uid >).setValue(newUser.toAnyObject())
```